# what kind of biology/evolution to create Xing Tian/Blemmye type of humanoid/monster?

Tags: science-based, biology, creature-design, evolution, xenobiology

here what [Xing Tian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xingtian) look like and the description in the wikipedia.

[image]

> Xingtian appears in chapter 7 of the Shanhaijing (Classic of Mountains and Seas), which states that he fought and lost against the supreme god to become the supreme divinity.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xingtian) The god decapitated Xingtian and buried his head on Changyang Mountain.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xingtian) However, Xingtian persevered, using his nipples as his eyes, using his navel as his mouth, and brandishing his shield and ax.

and here is the europe version name [Blemmye](https://fantasy-bestiary.fandom.com/wiki/Blemmye) for this type of monster.

[image]

> A people of headless men with faces on their torso, later called the Blemmyes, was mistakenly thought by ancient Greek historian Herodotus to dwell on the coast of Lybia, along with the Cynocephals. The name of 'Blemmyes' was added to the legend by Mela and used by Pliny the Younger. Latin compiler Solinus also reported that Blemmyes were born without their facial features, which were born separately and had to be added onto the baby manually.
>
> Various scholars in the Middle-Ages expanded on the Blemmyes' legends,
>   notably claiming that Alexander the Great met a tribe of Blemmyes
>   whose skin was golden, who had long beards that reached their knees;
>   in some versions, he was said to have captured thirty of them to show
>   the world, something he was unable to do because the Blemmyes died
>   during his journey. During this period, Blemmyes were sometimes
>   thought to inhabit Ethiopia or the Andaman Islands.
>
> Overall, Blemmyes are usually presented as sapient but barbaric
>   tribesmen, being notably never shown to wear any clothes at all. In
>   some later literary versions, they were even depicted as aggressive
>   and even cannibalistic.

so i wonder what evolutionary advantage or pressure to create this thing ? and would there any benefit if they have a body as the head like that ?

- unlike the Xing Tian one where it actually could not see, i want a functional mouth and eyes, also its not necessary for the young to not have facial features when born like Blemmyes either, i dont mind if it need to have bigger back to add the necessary functional organs in there as long its not the conventional head location.
- also its born like this, it never develop conventional head like human, so a metamorphosis kind of evolution where it gradually lose their conventional head like the equivalent of frog/human tail is out of the question.
- also the creature is intelligent like human.
- mimicry is out of the question, i want a real body head like in the image, not pseudo head as body but real body as the head.

feel free to edit my grammar and the tag to the appropriate one.

Comment: I don't see an evolution of this as possible (either from humans, or as convergent evolution), but you can try your luck with genetic engineering. Or maybe if you could relax the mimicry restriction a bit.

Answer (score 3):

**Anything is possible really, it just takes time and must yield an advantage along the way.**

What you're describing is essentially (over many generations) the following sequence:

1. slow, shortening of neck
2. disappearing of the neck altogether, with head now blended on top of body
3. slow bending of spinal column within the body, such that the skull starts to descend down to the rib cage
4. widening skull to width of body, with mouth directly positioned now in front of stomach.
5. no loss of brain power - and now you have your Xing Tian.

Now - here's the tricky bit. *Evolution must yield advantage at every step*. There is **no goal in evolution**, so from steps 1 to 5 each stage must be more successful than the prior stage. So perhaps here are the pressures to enable this:

1. Neck becomes obsolete because we no longer need to turn our head. Perhaps also its sexier?
2. Suddenly it's better to have the face descend the torso via the bending of the spinal column. Perhaps over hundreds of generations food can be consumed at stomach level, and perhaps also even this is sexier??
3. Eyes, mouth and nose all move to the positions as per your diagram. This would definitely come down to sex appeal too.

Not too far out of the question - mainly it's all based on sex. (ie. Men who have these tendencies are seen by women to be more stronger, more intelligent, or simply more desirable, and vice versa). There are certainly many courses evolution could take for us in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may evolve from a pangolin or other bipedal mammal that became larger. This pangolin would change its diet to fish, and gain tooth-like extensions to consume fish. Its forelegs would become unneeded, and would be lost. They may also gain larger and more mobile ears, due to sexual selection. These ears would become stronger and more mobile, until they ended up as full limbs. They may also become more intelligent, and gain a larger head. They then may become browsers, and become upright to reach higher, with their ear-limbs being used to grab things. With the ability to grasp objects and their intelligence, they would become sapient